# How to pull the data from Google Sheets to Webapp after submitting a value from form?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I managed to work on a form that submits data to google sheets in the A column, After submitting the form in Column A, the formula does the calcuations in Columns B,C,D, **I want to pull the data in Column B, Column C, and Column D results and display under the submit button**.

What modification should be done for the following could be done?

[My Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12G9g4aCbW41Js5wS33-7gTEO1r0SPh9lYauIJL53Jjk/edit#gid=0)
[image]

My Form
[image]

**Code.gs**

```
function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index')
      .evaluate();
}

/* @Include JavaScript and CSS Files */
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}



/* @Process Form */
function processForm(formObject) {
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12G9g4aCbW41Js5wS33-7gTEO1r0SPh9lYauIJL53Jjk/edit#gid=0";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  
  ws.appendRow([formObject.number_data]);
}
```

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <base target="_top">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
                        <p class="h4 mb-4 text-center">Values</p>

                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label for="number_data">Enter a Value</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="number_data" name="number_data" placeholder="Enter Number">
                            </div>
                          

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                    <div id="output"></div>
                </div>
            </div>      
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript.html**

```
<script>
  // Prevent forms from submitting.
  function preventFormSubmit() {
    var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
    for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
      forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      });
    }
  }
  window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);    
      
      
  function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
    google.script.run.processForm(formObject);
    document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `processForm()` function, Add a statement that will get the Col B, C, D of your newly added data and add a return statement which the callback function will use to write the data.

Try this:

**Code.gs**

```
/* @Process Form */
function processForm(formObject) {
  var url = "Sheet url";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  ws.appendRow([formObject.number_data]);
  var data = ws.getRange(ws.getLastRow(), 2, 1, 3).getValues();
  return data;
}
```

**JavaScript.html**

```
<script>
  // Prevent forms from submitting.
  function preventFormSubmit() {
    var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
    for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
      forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      });
    }
  }
  window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);    
      
      
  function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(writeData).processForm(formObject);
    document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
  }

  function writeData(data){
    document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = data[0][0];
    document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = data[0][1];
    document.getElementById("output3").innerHTML = data[0][2] ; 
  }

</script>
```

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <base target="_top">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
                        <p class="h4 mb-4 text-center">Values</p>

                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label for="number_data">Enter a Value</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="number_data" name="number_data" placeholder="Enter Number">
                            </div>
                          

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                    <div>
                      <div class="row">
                        <label>Data A : </label>
                        <div id="output1"></div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row">
                        <label>Data B : </label>
                        <div id="output2"></div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row">
                        <label>Data C : </label>
                        <div id="output3"></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>      
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Sheet:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

**References:**

- [Class google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)
- [getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)

Comment: J It worked :) excellent you are.  is it possible to have the value with the column heading so that it will be easy to understand e.g. Data A - 20500 Data B - 24500 Data C - 28500 in vertical results and not horizontal results.

Comment: @MuhammedAadhil - You can create separate div for each column headings and set the value of each div in the callback function. See my updated answer